# How do you run a Scala bash script with TypeSafe Activator?

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

How do you run a Scala shellscript with Activator?

Before using Activator you would use

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
```

but with Activator

```
#!/bin/sh
exec activator "$0" "$@"
```

does not work. I would prefer not having both Activator and a separate Scala install to avoid duplicate repositories if possible. If it is not possible knowing that would be helpful.

http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html#script_it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have the scala executable rolled into the activator download yet, so to do this you have to download Scala separately (http://www.scala-lang.org/download/ pick the "scala binaries" instead of activator). We would like activator to come with a bin/ directory that has the scala executable in it, but it currently doesn't.